# Filtering data query for all commands in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a system made in Laravel where absolutely all the tables have a column, `team_id`. This column obviously references a record in the teams table. Each team can have many users and one user can have many teams.

The user of a team can not, in any way, view the data of a team that he/she does not belong to.

Is there any way to run a command like `Sample_table::all()` and return all results only from the team previously chosen / logged by the user? I would not like to specify all the time when I run a query through Eloquent which team I am referring to. And it will also serve as security, one team cannot view data of another team.

Answer (score 1):

You can try *Query Scopes*.

**Writing Global Scopes**

```
<?php

namespace App\Scopes;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

class TeamScope implements Scope
{
    /**
     * Apply the scope to a given Eloquent query builder.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $builder
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model  $model
     * @return void
     */
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model)
    {
        $builder->where('team_id', '=', \Auth::user()->team_id); // Change it with correct team_id of your logged user
    }
}
```

**Applying Global Scope**

To assign a global scope to a model, you should override a given model's boot method and use the addGlobalScope method:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Scopes\TeamScope;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sample extends Model
{
    /**
     * The "booting" method of the model.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope(new TeamScope);
    }
}
```

After adding the scope, a query to `Sample::all()` will produce the following SQL:

```
select * from `samples` where `team_id` = 1
```

Here is the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#query-scopes) about *global scopes*